# Azure token not renewing in python script

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, ldap, token

I have a script through which I want to pull data from an API. I use Azure token for accessing the data. Unfortunately after the token expires, I got responses 401. For example:
'Error 401 getting details for group reports_scansafe_blocked: 401 Client Error:  for url: https://WEBSITE/api/v2/groups/reports_scansafe_blocked/details'.
My goal is to get the group owners information. Its over 3 million entries.

I have this script:

```
import requests
import csv
import os
import time

url = 'https://<WEBSITE HERE>/api/v2/groups/{}/details'
my_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer <AZURE TOKEN HERE>'}

# Open the CSV file for writing
csv_file_path = os.path.expanduser("C:/Users/FILE.CSV")
with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(['Group Name', 'Owner'])

    # Open the CSV file for reading groups from PLATFORM
    csv_file_path = os.path.expanduser("C:/Users/FILE.csv")
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as read_obj:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj)

        # Skip the header row
        next(csv_reader)


        def renew_token(token_id):
            renew_url = f'https://<WEBSITE HERE>/api/v1/tokens/<TOKEN ID HERE>/renew/'
            response = requests.post(renew_url, headers=my_headers)

            try:
                response.raise_for_status()
                response_json = response.json()
                new_token = response_json['<TOKEN HERE>']
                # Update the headers with the new token
                my_headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {new_token}'
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
                print(f"Error {e.response.status_code} renewing token: {e}")
                # Wait for a few seconds and try again
                time.sleep(5)
                renew_token(token_id)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f"Error parsing JSON response renewing token: {e}")
                # Wait for a few seconds and try again
                time.sleep(5)
                renew_token(token_id)

        # Loop through each group and get the owner's sAMAccountName
        for row in csv_reader:
            g = row[0]
            response = requests.get(url.format(g), headers=my_headers)

            try:
                # Try to parse the response JSON
                response.raise_for_status()
                response_json = response.json()
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
                # Log and skip failed requests
                print(f"Error {e.response.status_code} getting details for group {g}: {e}")
                continue
            except ValueError as e:
                # Log and skip invalid JSON responses
                print(f"Error parsing JSON response for group {g}: {e}")
                continue

            if 'owner' in response_json and response_json['owner'] is not None:
                owner = response_json['owner'].get('sAMAccountName', '')
            else:
                owner = ''

            # Debugging: print the response JSON
            print(response_json)

            # Write the group name and owner to the CSV file
            writer.writerow([g, owner])
```

Comment: instead of `continue` in handling `requests.exceptions.HTTPError`, try calling renew_token(). Right now you define the renew_token function, but don't actually use it.

Comment: Try looking up this URL - 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/applied-ai-services/immersive-reader/how-to-cache-token.md.[1][4]